# ¿#define array? preprocesador C

Tags: c, arduino, preprocesador

estoy tratando de hacer una librería para arduino, aprendo de forma autodidacto a si que no tengo a quien preguntar, a si que me ha surgido la siguiente duda, en mi librería hay un apartado de configuración en el que asignas los valores en un fichero .h, por ello, para facilitarlo visualmente querría poner un #define con un array pero no se si es posible, lo he intentado de varias formas.

```
#define array[2] = {0, 1}
#define array[2] {0, 1}
#define array (0, 1)
```

No me ha servido ninguna y no se me ocurre ninguna, he buscado en Internet y no he encontrado nada, he encontrado [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824703/array-format-for-define-c-preprocessor), pero no entiendo ni patata y lo que escriben lo he probado y no me ha funcionado, a si que si alguien me puede ayudar por favor lo agradecería mucho.

dicho de otro modo, yo tengo un grupo de constantes como `#define` y quiero que en vez de ser un listado sea un array:

esta asi:

```
#define PIN1 2
#define PIN2 3
#define PIN3 4
#define PIN4 5
#define PIN5 6
#define PIN6 7
```

y pretendo que estuviera en un array, algo asi:

```
#define PINS[6] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

para asi poder usarlo desde la funcion que sea:

```
Serial.print(PINS[2]);
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio ¡gracias por participar!. Sintiendolo mucho no entiendo nada tu pregunta ¿Cuál es el objetivo que buscas? ¿Podrías reformular tu pregunta?

Comment: Claro, a lo que me refiero es que estoy tratando de hacer un array con el preprocesador algo como (int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};) pero en version #define, es decir un array con un #define, así quedaría mas ordenado que poner muchos #define

Comment: Si te estoy entendiendo bien, tu intención es tener un array que puedas definir en una macro (`#define`) y después usar esa macro para *importar* el array en cualquier archivo ¿es eso? ¿eres consciente que esa práctica te crearía una **copia del array** en todos los archivos en que usases la macro?

Comment: Si, soy consciente y eso es lo que pretendo, incluyendo la copia del array, esa era la idea que quería, de esa forma puedo llamarla desde cualquier archivo en la cual la importe, he modificado la pregunta, a ver si así es mas clara.

Answer (score 1):

He leido el enlace que das y he implementado algunos de esos ejemplos y creo que el mas facil que puedas utlizar es este

```
#define MODE 0

#define DECLARE_ARRAYS_WITH_SIZES(S1, S2, S3) \
int arr1[S1]; \
int arr2[S2]; \
int arr3[S3];

#if MODE == 0
DECLARE_ARRAYS_WITH_SIZES(3, 6, 7)
#elif MODE == 1
DECLARE_ARRAYS_WITH_SIZES(8, 2, 1)
#endif
```

Asi le das valores predeterminados y los puedes usar. El codigo completo de ejemplo seria asi

```
#include <iostream>

#define MODE 0

#define DECLARE_ARRAYS_WITH_SIZES(S1, S2, S3) \
int arr1[S1] = {1,2,3}; \
int arr2[S2] = {2,6,8,8}; \
int arr3[S3] = {1,2,5,8};

 #if MODE == 0
 DECLARE_ARRAYS_WITH_SIZES(3, 6, 7)
 #elif MODE == 1 
 DECLARE_ARRAYS_WITH_SIZES(8, 2, 1)
 #endif

 using namespace std;

 int main() {

cout << arr1[1];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pero aquí el array es una int  y se usa el `#define` para definir la capacidad de los siguientes arrays, no?

Comment: Si no era eso lo que querías? Sino es así aclarame para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que pretendo es hacer un array con valores numéricos en el `#define` y poder llamarlos desde alguna parte del código, la sintaxis de array ya la tengo: `#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT { 100, 100, 400, 95 }` pero no se como llamar a la posición 2 por ejemplo. Lo que he puesto es como se hace en marlin, un programa para controlar impresoras 3D.

Comment: O sea que lo q te puse no te sirve? Y lo de las impresoras esta fuera de mi rango jaja ... Tu lo que querés es definir un arreglo como un #define? Sinceramente con los conocimientos que tengo no creo que se pueda ser... Ojalá me equivoque voy a investigar y si algo te ayudo

Comment: Te lo agradezco muchísimo, yo llevo bastante buscando y no dejo de buscar, pero no encuentro nada fuera de ese programa, de todas formas aunque prefiera usar el preprocesador si no se puede usaré una un listado de #define y ya está, muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

En arduino un array se puede definir de varias formas pero puedes hacerlo:

```
int PINS[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Para usar como `PINS[2];`

Comment: Yo pretendía usarlo con un `#define` el int se usarlo, he investigado en el marlin, un programa para usar CNCs y hace varias de estas con `#define`, las define así:

    `#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT   { 100, 100, 400, 95 } `

Esa es una linea para definir los steps por milímetro para el uso de la maquina, con esto se como definir el array, pero no se como llamar por ejemplo a la posición 2 del mismo.